# Exclude sig querystring parameter from any auth check in Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using an Azure Blob to serve static assets such as html, images, css and js for a facebook iframe app.

I am working on the integration of that app as an odnoklassniki.ru (ok.ru) iframe app. So in the app config, let's say I setup the app url pointing to `index.html`.
When I open the app, the iframe will include some [querystring parameters from the social network](http://apiok.ru/wiki/display/api/Application+parameters).

> https://****.blob.core.windows.net/****/index.html?web_server=ok.ru&first_start=0&logged_user_id=1234&**sig**=3688aaa2d712f7a7540681e1234a3039&new_sig=1&...

As one of the parameters included is `sig`, and that conflicts with the signature for [shared blobs authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/), the following error will be returned:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>
    Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:aabaf862-0001-0009-58a4-91b035000000 Time:2015-05-18T19:57:59.5979366Z
  </Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>sr is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Is there any workaround or azure config to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change how blob storage  works, or the querystring parameters it uses. You'd have to change the parameters you're using from the social networks you're working with. Or encode the querystring content received from the social network, or remove it from the querystring altogether and move it somewhere else (to some other store). Or maybe other solutions. But bottom line: You cannot change Azure blob storage to ignore such parameters as `sig`.

Comment: Thanks! I will move to some other storage since I cannot change how that social network works. I guess wishful thinking made me ask this haha